# Google Calendar - Python - Sync

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, synchronization

I've been researching and having a hard time trying to figure out how to work my solution out. Basically my end goal is to be able to log into Google Calendar and grab a dates events and work with the information. If possible, be able to use multiple accounts. I've done some research and have come across Google's own API but I just don't know where to start.

Comment: That's seems like great start to me:
http://code.google.com/p/googlecalendarsync/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the API documentation (with python code examples):
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol

you will need this library:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/

more concrete you need to use this class:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/calendar/client.py

in order to get the data from a users, you will need to have the auth_token for each of them.

I'm not sure if this API allows you to use direct login instead of auth_token.

UPDATE:
current API version is 3: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: The API you link to is deprecated. The v3 api is the current one.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Calendar V3 Python Client**

Google Calendar V3 provides an API client that can be authenticated using the following: access_token, refresh_token, client_id, and client_secret

https://github.com/priyadarshy/google-calendar-v3